# Hover main menu li + a

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working in the menu in this web[WebSite](http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv), but I have a problem.

I need when hover the main menu, put this tag "a" to other color.

html code:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-159"><a href="http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/">Home</a></li> 
    <li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-160"><a href="http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/historia/">Quiénes Somos</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-161" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-161"><a href="http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/historia/">Historia</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-162" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-162"><a href="http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/mision/">Misión</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-163" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-163"><a href="http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/vision/">Visión</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-164" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-164"><a href="http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/sistema-integrado-gestion/">Sistema Integrado Gestión</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-165" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-165"><a href="http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/politicas/">Políticas de Gestión</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

This is my css code but not working:

```
.mainMenu .menu li.menu-item:hover + a{
    color: red !important;
}
```

Any help please.

Comment: Please post all relevant code in the question itself. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do this:

```
.mainMenu .menu li.menu-item > a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

and if you just want to style the links in the sub menu then do this:

```
.mainMenu .menu li.menu-item ul li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

and if you want to hover `li` :

```
.mainMenu .menu > li.menu-item:hover > a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: See my edit, the problem is that i have a submenu with li and inside tags "a"

Comment: In that case you need the direct child selector > . If you want to style the links in the sub menu you need to change it to li ul li a. See updated answer.

Comment: Ok I got it , but I want to hover in li and Tag a will be color in main menu , not in submenu

Comment: If you want to hover li then apply the :hover on li. Will add to my answer

Comment: yes, I understand but this way put all tags a in color also all in the submenu, I want only the main menu, this is my problem

Comment: Just FYI the + selector is the adjacent selector, not a child

Comment: Make sure you use the direct child selector > as in my example

Comment: The same problem, this way put all tags a in color also all in the submenu, I want only the main menu.

Comment: Add the direct child selector to li a, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/twt1rs1v/

Comment: Probably best to also remove the !important on all a tags unless you really really really need it...